# Android custom compound component's contents won't appear

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create a custom view, a calendar. The views inside this component are inflated from a xml layout. I have studied several tutorials and three or four similar (or even identical) questions on stack overflow but nothing seems to work. I'd appreciate it if you could point out the problem. Thanks in advance and here are the codes.

kcalendar_view.xml // the layout for the custom view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnKCalendarNavLeft"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/kcalendar_nav_button_bg"
            android:text="&lt;" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txvKCalendarNavTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnKCalendarNavRight"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/kcalendar_nav_button_bg"
            android:text=">" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewKCalendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="7" >
    </GridView>

</merge>
```

KCalendarView.java // the custom view's class

```
package ir.kcoder.KCalendarView;

import ir.kcoder.persiancalendarweather.R;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.samanpr.jalalicalendar.JalaliCalendar;
import com.samanpr.jalalicalendar.JalaliCalendar.YearMonthDate;


public class KCalendarView extends LinearLayout {
    private YearMonthDate currentJalaliDate;
    private int parentWidth, parentHeight;
    private Button leftButton, rightButton;
    private GridView gridView;
    private KCalendarAdapter calendarAdapter;
    private Context context;
    private View inflated;

    public KCalendarView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public KCalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kcalendar_view, this, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        init(getContext());
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        YearMonthDate currentGregDate = new YearMonthDate(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE));
        currentJalaliDate = JalaliCalendar.gregorianToJalali(currentGregDate);

        leftButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnKCalendarNavLeft);
        rightButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnKCalendarNavRight);
        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridViewKCalendar);

        if(gridView != null) {
            calendarAdapter = new KCalendarAdapter(context, currentJalaliDate.getYear(),
                    currentJalaliDate.getMonth());
            gridView.setAdapter(calendarAdapter);
        }
    }

    public void nextMonth() {

    }

    public void prevMonth() {

    }

//  @Override
//  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
//      parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
//      parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
//      this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight);
//      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
//  }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml // I use this tag to include the custom view in my app

```
<ir.kcoder.KCalendarView.KCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/kCalendarView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ir.kcoder.KCalendarView.KCalendarView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Try this I think it should work

```
public class KCalendarView extends LinearLayout {

    private YearMonthDate currentJalaliDate;

    private int parentWidth, parentHeight;

    private Button leftButton, rightButton;
    private GridView gridView;

    private KCalendarAdapter calendarAdapter;

    public KCalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        doInflate();
    }

    private void doInflate() {
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.kcalendar_view, this);

        leftButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnKCalendarNavLeft);
        rightButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnKCalendarNavRight);
        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridViewKCalendar);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        YearMonthDate currentGregDate = new YearMonthDate(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE));
        currentJalaliDate = JalaliCalendar.gregorianToJalali(currentGregDate);
        calendarAdapter = new KCalendarAdapter(context, currentJalaliDate.getYear(), currentJalaliDate.getMonth());
        gridView.setAdapter(calendarAdapter);
    }

    public void nextMonth() {

    }

    public void prevMonth() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, but unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: One word: AWESOME. Thanks a lot, I was struggling with this problem the whole day. The main problem was with the onLayout method.